# How to make inner div to match at least the height of the body?

Tags: html, css

Here's is an example of what I want working fine if the div is a child element of the body using min-height:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.outer-wrap{
  min-height: 100%;
}
.table-layout{
  display: table;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-cell{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 2%;
}
.blue{
  background: #55a;
}
.grey{
  background: #bbb;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="outer-wrap">
    <div class="table-layout">
      <div class="table-cell blue">
        test
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell grey">
        content<br />
        <br />
        content<br />
        <br />
        content<br />
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OjxmGj

However, when I add an outer div with min-height:100%; the inner div no longer fills the height of the body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.outer-wrap{
  min-height: 100%;
}
.table-layout{
  display: table;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-cell{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 2%;
}
.blue{
  background: #55a;
}
.grey{
  background: #bbb;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table-layout">
      <div class="table-cell blue">
        test
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell grey">
        content<br />
        <br />
        content<br />
        <br />
        content<br />
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JyrNVj

It's not really practical for me to update the entire layout to get this working so I'm hoping there is another way to make this work without removing the outer div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert "height: 100vh;" to the inner div.

Refer to this [SO post on Viewport-Percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window) for more details.

Using Inspect, this seemed to produce the desired results.

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly and I've never even heard of vh before! Extremely useful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just add **`height: 1px`** to the class `outer-wrap` and keep `min-height: 100%`.

```css
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.outer-wrap{
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}
.table-layout{
  display: table;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-cell{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 2%;
}
.blue{
  background: #55a;
}
.grey{
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrap">
  <div class="table-layout">
    <div class="table-cell blue">
      test
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell grey">
      content<br />
      <br />
      content<br />
      <br />
      content<br />
      <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I want the outer div to expand beyond 100% if needed.

Comment: Ok. try having `height: 1px` to outerwrap. Check updated answer. See if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `min-width` to `width` on both elements and add `overflow-y: visible;` to allow it to extend vertically if necessary:

```
.outer-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
.table-layout {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: visible;
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzVRvN